# Angular 2 image src as function return

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive, angular2-template

In my angular 2 application i have a comment system like the facebook's one, when users can comment on a post, i have to display the message, the user name and the user profile image.

My problem is that the Web service send me the username,message to display, the user's image id but not the image itself, so i have to get it with an other http call.

**CODE EXEMPLE :**

app.component.ts :

```
<app-reviews [comment] = 'Comment| async'></app-reviews> // async is juste          an error, i know tha when use subscribe i cant use async
```

So here i pass the comment to the comment component with @Input, the comment object contain the username, the message and the image id and i have to make a http call to get the image.

i have tried to getIt like this :

```
  <div *ngFor='let com of comment'>
  <img alt="image" [src]='getUserImage(com.authorImageId)'>
   ....
```

but i know that this method can cause issue since getUserImage() will execute on every change detection cycle.

How can i do that the best way ?

**UPDATE**

Function code :

```
 getUserImage(userImageID: string) {
this._profileService.getImageById(userImageID)
.subscribe((response: any) => {
  return  response._body;

});
```

Comment: Could you please show your function code?

Comment: @NacimIdjakirene code should be using `.map` instead of `.subscribe`

Comment: @PankajParkar can you explain me why ?

Comment: @NacimIdjakirene You can't return a data from subscribe function, by using map you can grab the data and return, its like a stream of data..

Comment: when have you .subscribe you must delete | async

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem, I stored the returned user Image and the img only executes the function if the user Image does not exist.

```
<img alt="image" [src]='userImage ? userImage :getUserImage(com.authorImageId)'>
```

However you should instead have a generic default image so the image isn't undefined to use until the server creates the userImage:

```
<img alt="image" [src]='userImage ? userImage : defaultImage'>
```